# Mac Issue with ng command

Tags: angular

ng -v

user_name: No such file or directory

command not  working in mac.

Please help. I tried a to use all the angular commands, but not working

Answer (score 0):

use no dash with the command. Just

```
ng v
```

Comment: You may not have Angular installed. Have you followed the steps here? https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

For me `ng --version` works. Check if your Path is updated with the angular command lines.